# :not() is inherited to the first nested element if I use a classname

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, css-selectors

I have a c-checkbox component in Vue with 4 different variants. In these checkboxes I need to render a background-image in all variants apart from the one I call c-switch. If I use `input[type="checkbox"]` then it works (See example). If I target the classname, it doesn't. Any ideas why this behavior?

So my goal is to render this icon in everything apart from c-checkbox--switch.

```
  // Current solution
  &:not(.c-checkbox--switch) {
    & > input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:after {
      background-image: url("some url");
    }
  }

  // What I want to achieve
  &:not(.c-checkbox--switch) {
    & > &__input:checked + label:after {
      background-image: url("some url");
    }
  }
```

How these 2 are translated:

**With type="checkbox"**

[image]

**With &__input class**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You write that if you target the class name, it doesn't work. That's because you are not targetting a class name?

If `__input` is the class name, it should be `.__input`. If the class name is `&__input`, I'm pretty sure that is an invalid name - should start with `_`, `-` or an English letter.

```
&:not(.c-checkbox--switch) {
    & > .__input:checked + label:after {
        background-image: url("some url");
    }
}
```

Of course, I'm not really sure what those ampersands are doing in the first place.

Comment: __input is the classname. Double underscore just follows the BEM convention for this element. So ur solution doesn't solve the problem, but thanks for answering <3

Comment: Basically with &__input in SCSS, you target the parent element.
c-checkbox__input = c-checkbox { &__input }